# Как правильно задизайнить сервис для отправки уведомлений?

Tags: архитектура, уведомления, микросервисы, push-уведомления

я сейчас занимаюсь дизайном сервиса нотификаций, пришел к общей концепции и она выглядит следующим образом:

```
transport configuration 
          -> gateway 
                    -> email service
                    -> telegram service
                    -> client service
```

gateway - это сервис, который дает людям возможность создавать конфигурации и отправлять сообщения
т.е человек создал конфигурацию для отправки сообщений по email и в следующий раз он может вызвать команду Notify с созданной конфигурацией. Notify сам поймет, что ему передали конфигурацию для email сервиса и через email сервис просто отправит сообщение

email, telegram сервисы мне очень понятны, а вот client - совсем нет
идея client сервиса следующая: клиентом может быть кто угодно - от веб приложения до какой-нибудь авалонии. Отправлять сообщения, наверное, нужно брокером, но как это правильно делать, в голове не укладывается